# JQuery plugin for fluid scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

Does anyone knows jquery library for smooth element scroll like [this one](http://www.lecoldeclaudine.com/fr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want elements to move at different speeds? If so you might want to look at some  [Paralax scrolling libraries](http://www.desiznworld.com/2013/07/free-jquery-parallax-scrolling-plugins.html)

Comment: Yep, i know bout parallax but i tried to find complete solution.